# Match everything after word using only regex

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I'm trying to set up a ShareX custom engine, and after the upload I'm given the full url, for instance `http://foo.com/HF139hR` and I can work that string with regex before copying it to clipboard. What I want to do is to get only the last part of the url, `HF139hR` so I can throw it into another url, say `http://foo.com/?viewer=HF139hR`. So far I was using the expression`\w+$` to grab it but sometimes I can get an upload error, and that will also get the last word of the error message and pass it to `?viewer=`.

Doing my research I found `\bfoo.com\/\K\S+`, which is exactly what I want, but unfortunately it is not supported on javascript.

Comment: What is the tool you are using? Please add this to your question.

Comment: The tool is [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/), a quick-sharing software, and I was trying to set up a custom uploader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> \bfoo.com/\K\S+

`\bfoo.com\/(\S+)`

You can use a similar one and grab the `group 1` or `capture 1`

Comment: That would match `foo.com/` too, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Gus it would match that but you need to grab the `group 1 ` from it and use it for other purpose.Do use the `match` but `match.group 1`

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but in the software I'm using I can't replace or use javascript. The result of the regexp gets stored in a variable and that's it. See the pic: http://i.imgur.com/UgQQbPc.png In this case, `$1$` is the result of `\w+$`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I just realized that the software I'm using will treat the upload as complete even if the output is an error message, which is what I was trying to avoid. So there is no way to fix it through regex. I'll see if I can contact them for more info. Still, your answer has the correct regex for what I was trying to do, so I'll check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex: `/\/(\w+)(\?+.*)*$/` and get the capturing group between `()`, this will avoid the part of the upload error which starts with `?` like in the example `?viewer=$1$, you can try it here:

```js
var url="http://foo.com/HF139hR?=viewer=$1$";
var reg=/\/(\w+)(\?+.*)*$/;
alert(url.match(reg)[1]);
```

And if you use only the `url="http://foo.com/HF139hR"` as a url it will also match the same thing.
And you can take a look at this **Regex** **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pN5lH1/1)** where you can see the match information.